# I am unable to predict: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'check' not found

Tags: r

Please, I need your help to resolve this issue.

I created a spam filtering model using random forest.
I am trying to predict with the random forest model I trained and saved as .rds file.

I keep getting the error

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'check' not found

Here is my code

--- code ---

```
library(randomForest)

library(caret)

library(tm)

library(caTools)

library(dplyr)

library(gmodels)

#library(Boruta)

library(mlbench)

#library(ROCR)

#Type <- c("ham")

Text <- c("If you handle newsletter for can multiple websites")

df <- data.frame(Type, Text)

corpus = df$Text

#remove non ASCII codes and emoticons

corpus = gsub("[^\x01-\x7F]", "", corpus)

#remove HTML tags

corpus = gsub("<.*/>","",corpus)

#Remove all the URLs
corpus = gsub(" ?(f|ht)tp(s?)://(.*)[.][a-z]+", "", corpus)

#remove numbers
corpus = removeNumbers(corpus)

#max no of characters in a mail

max(nchar(corpus))

corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(corpus))

corpus = tm_map(corpus , tolower)

corpus = tm_map(corpus , removePunctuation)

removeURL <- content_transformer(function(x) gsub("(f|ht)tp(s?)://\\S+", "", x, perl=T))

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeURL)

toSpace <- content_transformer(function (x , pattern ) gsub(pattern, " ", x))

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, "/")

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, "@")

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, "\\|")

corpus = tm_map(corpus ,removeWords , stopwords("english"))

corpus = tm_map(corpus , stemDocument)

dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)

dtm

sptdm = removeSparseTerms(dtm , 0.98)

#sptdm = dtm

sptdm

emailsparse= as.data.frame(as.matrix(sptdm))

names(emailsparse) =  make.names(names(emailsparse))

emailsparse$labels = as.factor(df$Type)
set.seed(123)

##loading model
RF_model <- readRDS("RF_model_2022.09.15.13.35.37.rds")

#RF_model
class(emailsparse)

summary(RF_model)

predict(RF_model, newdata = 

emailsparse, type='prob')
```

--- end of code ---

[Here is the link to the model .rds file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tywyVBbOxH2w9vejS3ti9kP8hPYYYgg0/view?usp=drivesdk)

Please, what am I doing wrongly and how do I fix this?

Comment: Ensure that `emailsparse` cobtains a column `"check"`.

Comment: It's a text classification problem. To ensure "check" is part of the column I will have to add "check" to the Text I am trying to predict. Then it will say object 'can' not found. I guess there is something I am doing wrongly. I have added the model could you please test the cod?.

Comment: I don't need to test. The error message is clear. You have a model that uses a variable "check" as predictor. You need to provide the model with this predictor if you want it to predict.

Comment: Thank you for your help. How do I add all the variables my model is using as a predictor without typing them out manually as part of the Text I am trying to predict? I apologize if my ignorance is irritating.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is that I have a spam filtering model. I want to pass an email message to it to determine if it is spam or ham.